# What is the code for passing an electrical wire through a joist?

Tags: electrical

I want to wire a canless light in a dark closet.

I want to run the wire from the adjoining room to the light via the attic.

What is the code for passing a wire through a joist? (like in the picture)

[image: my attic]

Comment: I think the building code allows about 30 or 40% depth of the joist for the hole, the smaller the better.  Electrical code requires nail plates if the cable is within  1.5 inches of the narrow(nailing) edge

Comment: How deep are your joists?

Answer (score 1):

Joists should not be notched - holes should go through the centre, an be kept relatively small. The bending moment is much higher towards the top and bottom of the joist, so losing material in the centre affects its load carrying capacity and stiffness the least.

Answer (score 1):

Drill bored holes 2" from the top or bottom. Electrical and Building Code issues address this.

In the NEC several sections apply, notably 300.4(A)(1) instruct when bored holes are less than 1.25" from the edge a nail plate is required. (But see building code below.)

NEC 300.4(A)(2) does allow using a nail plate if notching, but first qualifies with stating "Where there is no objection due to weakening building structure..."

That statement normally is a deferral to the Building Code, which typically says something like:

> **R502.1.11.1 [IRC 502.8.1] Sawn lumber**. Notches in solid lumber joists, rafters and beams shall not exceed one-sixth of the depth of
> the member, shall not be longer than one-third of the depth of the
> member and shall not be located in the middle one-third of the span.
> Notches at the ends of the member shall not exceed one-fourth the
> depth of the member. The tension side of members 4 inches (102 mm) or
> greater in nominal thickness shall not be notched except at the ends
> of the members. The diameter of holes bored or cut into members shall
> not exceed one-third the depth of the member. Holes shall not be
> closer than 2 inches (51 mm) to the top or bottom of the member, or to
> any other hole located in the member. Where the member is also
> notched, the hole shall not be closer than 2 inches (51 mm) to the
> notch.
> **R502.1.11.2 [IRC 502.8.2] Engineered wood products.** Cuts,
> notches and holes bored in trusses, structural composite lumber,
> structural glue-laminated members or I-joists are prohibited except
> where permitted by the manufacturer's recommendations or where the
> effects of such alterations are specifically considered in the
> design of the member by a registered design professional.

([See illustrations](https://up.codes/s/irc-502-8-cutting-drilling-and-notching))