# Electrical code question: Wire from a switch or a light fixture?

Tags: electrical

I want to wire a light off of an existing fixture.

Is there a code that dictates running from a wall switch or an existing fixture?

**Option 1:**

[image: floor view]

**Option 2:**

[image: side view]

References question:
[Installing a canless light in a dark closet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/279539/what-is-the-code-for-passing-an-electrical-wire-through-a-joist)

Comment: Both are allowed.  If from the light fixture to the switch you need a cable with black, red and white plus ground.  If power to the switch first you just need black and white plus ground cable to the light.  Usually use the one that is easier to wire/shortest distance.

Answer (score 3):

Code requires supply and return currents to be routed together, in the same conduit or cable. What this means for your new light fixture is that the cable from the new light must go to a location where there are both switched-hot and neutral available. The existing light is always a safe bet; the light switch is a maybe -- it depends on how your house is wired.

Open up the switch junction box and find out what's inside. If there is a single cable with its two conductors attached to the switch terminals, and no un-connected white-insulated conductor, then you have an old style "switch loop." In this case your new light would have to be wired to the existing light.

If that switch box does have an un-connected white conductor, or if it has multiple cables/conductors, then you can choose to run the cable for the new light from the switch or from the existing light. It would be possible to do either in a code-compliant way.